# Enable PHP Extension (php_odbc.dll) on Azure

Tags: php, azure, odbc

I have started working with Azure and testing connectivity to an Microsoft SQL Database. I would like to utilize our current php_odbc.dll extension instead of using the PDO approach.

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE ";          
  //perform the query 
  $result=odbc_exec($conn, $query);
```

I have performed the steps for adding an extension by configuring via App Setting and configuring via ini settings. Both ways cause my main index page to throw a 500 error. My main index.php only includes the phpinfo(); function for testing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/app-service/web-sites-php-configure#configure-via-app-setting

Question: How do I enable the php_odbc.dll ext on Azure? PHP version is 7.3

Comment: Do you see any errors in the app logs under D:\home\LogFiles?
Also, the dll needs to be non-thread-safe, VC9 or VC11 compatible version of PHP for Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you were using Azure WebApp for Windows to deploy your PHP app with Azure SQL Database connection by `php_odbc.dll`.

As I known, Azure WebApp for Windows has been installed several versions of PHP runtime with many extensions, which include PHP 7.3 that is under the path `D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP` as the figure below and I checked `php_odbc.dll` whether be exists via Kudo console `https://<your webapp name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`

[image]

Then, I moved to `v7.3` to view the `php.ini` file to check the `php_odbc.dll` extension whether be enabled.

[image]

[image]

As the figure above, you can see there is no `php_odbc` declared in `php.ini`, so it's not enabled default. And Azure regulates all files and directories under `D:\` (except `D:\home`) that can not be changed by customers, so to try to edit `php.ini` to enable `php_odbc` will cause error issue.

[image]

So the solution is to refer to the section [`How to: Enable extensions in the default PHP runtime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/app-service/web-sites-php-configure#how-to-enable-extensions-in-the-default-php-runtime) of the offical document `Configure PHP in Azure App Service` as the figure below to enable a default existing extension.

[image]

By default, there may not be a directory named `ini` in the path `D:\home\site` which need to be created by yourself, and then to create a file named `extensions.ini` under it and edit it to add the extension name or the absoluted path of `php_odbc`.

```
; Enable Extensions
extension=php_odbc
; Or use its absoluted path, such as for 32bit platform
; extension=D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.3\ext\php_odbc.dll
```

After restart your Azure WebApp, you can try your PHP page again.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you. I had to modify my ini file with the correct extension;  extension=php_odbc

Comment: @NickKester Glad to hear that. Could you mark my answer? Thanks!