# Does Azure PHP 7 web app have Oracle drivers?

Tags: php, oracle, azure

I'm trying to find out if Azure Web App under App Services running on PHP 7 comes with support and drivers for Oracle database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Azure WebApp on Windows, please refer to the MSDN offical blog [`Access Oracle Databases from Azure Web Apps using OCI8 drivers with PHP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/azureossds/access-oracle-databases-from-azure-web-apps-using-oci8-drivers-with-php) to know how to do.

Otherwise, you can refer to my answer for the other SO thread [Enable PHP Extension (php_odbc.dll) on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59795602/enable-php-extension-php-odbc-dll-on-azure/59822450#59822450) to enable the `php_odbc` extension, and then follow the document [`Connecting to Oracle from PHP using ODBC Driver for Oracle`](https://www.devart.com/odbc/oracle/docs/php.htm) to connect Oracle using ODBC in PHP.

If you are using Azure WebApp on Linux, the document above for connecting Oracle using ODBC in PHP also be suitable for Linux.

Or you need to refer to the offical document [`Configure a custom Linux container for Azure App Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container) to install `pecl` via add the command `RUN apt install php-pear` on Ubuntu image (because the default Alpine image does not have the `pecl` package), then to use `pecl` install `oci8` via command `pecl install oci8`. These are all configured in the Dockerfile.

My recommended solution is to follow the MSDN blog I mentioned above to install on Azure WebApp on Windows, it's so easy.